# Having trouble registering custom user for 'Apps' directory structure

Tags: django

I have a Django project, but instead of having the django project and all of the apps within the same directory, I have created a directory called 'Apps' where I put all of my apps.   For example the structure might look like this:

django_project
 -settings.py
 .......
 - wsgi.py
apps
 - app1
      - admin.py
      ......
      - views.py
 - login_app
      - admin.py
      ......
      - views.py

I want to add a custom user to the login_app.   However I am getting a problem when I change AUTH_USER_MODEL in the django_project to the following:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'login_app.User'

AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'login_app.User' that has not been installed
```

I have tried changing it to 'apps.login_app.User' but this raises an error.

How do I register a 'User' when the directory structure is apps/login_app ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'apps.app1.apps.AppOneConfig', 
    'apps.login_app.apps.LoginAppConfig'  ⬅⬅⬅⬅⬅
     
]
    ....
   AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'apps.login_app.User'
```

**apps/login_app/apps.py:**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class LoginAppConfig(AppConfig):
            ⬇⬇⬇
    name = 'apps.login_app'
```

Please tell me this works or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it looks really good.   I will try it, but it might take a day or so until I get some spare time to test it out.